# C++ - Incomplete type not allowed while declaring struct and class

Tags: c++, c, class, typedef, incomplete-type

I am trying to define a class that has an element that is of that type. to put it into better words:

```
class Cell {
public:
    int row;
    int col;
    Cell parent;
};
```

I'm working under Visual studio and `parent` gets underlined with the error: `incomplete type is not allowed`. I believe this is because I am referencing something whose declaration has not yet been completed. So I tried to do it a bit differently, by defining it as a type:

```
typedef struct s_cell {
    int row;
    int col;
    struct s_cell parent;
} Cell;
```

I get the same issue. I'm sure it is for the same reason.

Comment: If you put a `Cell`inside a `Cell` then that `Cell` will also contain a `Cell` which in turn will contain a `Cell` with another `Cell` in that... etc... no?

Comment: A class (or struct) can contain a **pointer** to a class (or struct) of the same type, but cannot contain an instance of the same type, since that would result in infinite recursion.

Comment: @user3386109 that did the trick thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To answer your question, let's pretend this was allowed. (For the sake of simplicity, and because it's what I'm more familiar with, I'm going to use the C `struct` case as an example. The C++ case is identical, with keywords swapped if you're using a `class` instead.)

A variable of a `struct` type is as large as all the members of the `struct`. So, let's say you have the following:

```
struct foo {
  int x;
  int y;
};
```

Assuming that `int` is 4 bytes (a common assumption in many modern platforms), a variable of type `struct foo` takes 8 bytes (twice 4, because it contains two `int` members) in memory and contains two integers in it.

Now, let's do this:

```
struct bar {
  int a;
  int b;
  struct bar another; // "bar another;" would be OK in C++, not in C
};
```

So a `struct bar` variable will be... how long? You have 4 for each `int`, so 8, plus... its own size, since it contains a *copy* of itself. So `sizeof(struct bar) == 8 + sizeof(struct bar)`. This doesn't make sense. The contents of the `struct` don't make sense either — it contains two `int` members, and then... another `struct bar` with two more, which contains *yet another* `struct bar` with two more, and so on *ad infinitum*. You'd end up with a case of infinite recursion.

What you probably want to do in this case is to have a *pointer* to another `struct bar`, which may or may not be null:

```
struct bar {
  int a;
  int b;
  struct bar * another;
};
```

This has well-defined contents (two `int` members and a pointer member), with a well-defined size (16 bytes, for instance, assuming the pointer takes 8).

Going back to your cell, you'd have:

```
class Cell {
public:
  int row;
  int col;
  Cell * parent;
};
```

Now instead of an incomplete type, you have a *pointer to an incomplete type*, which is allowed. (Consider `void`, defined as an incomplete type, and `void *`, which is therefore a pointer to an incomplete type. You can never use the former as a type for a member, but you can always use the latter.)

And in fact, at least one of your cells will have no parent; *something* will probably be the root and ancestor of all your cells. That one cell will have `nullptr` as the value of `parent`.